# How to index first row

Tags: user-interface, powershell, datagridview

On a dataGridView, I have the first line for names of columns.

How I can fix this one, and sort the rest of the grid ?

My code :

```
$dataGridView1.Width = 500
$dataGridView1.Height = 200
$dataGridView1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$dataGridView1.Name = "dataGrid1"
$dataGridView1.DataMember = ""
$dataGridView1.Left = 30
$dataGridView1.Top = 55
$dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4
$row = @( "Machine", "IP" , "OS", "Domain")
$dataGridView1.Rows.Add($row)
$dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index
$dataGridView1.ReadOnly = $true
$dataGridView1.CurrentCell = $dataGridView1.Item(0,1)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using Column name like this?

```
$dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4    
#$row = @( "Machine", "IP" , "OS", "Domain")

$dataGridView1.Columns[0].name = "Machine"
$dataGridView1.Columns[1].name = "IP"
$dataGridView1.Columns[2].name = "OS"
$dataGridView1.Columns[3].name = "Domain"
```

Comment: Thanks you, that what I want !